# setting ShowInMenus to false has no effect

Tags: php, menu, silverstripe

I do set in some of the pages I created:

```
   static $defaults = array( 
      'ShowInMenus' => false 
   );
```

However this seems to have zero effect. The Page is still displayed in the drop down menu when I create a new Page in the CMS as well as in the SiteTree.

This is SilverStripe 2.4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This static is for hiding pages from menus generated in the frontend. What you are describing sounds like you want to be able to hide pages in the backend, so they can't be created. Is that correct? If that's the case, you should have a look at the $allowed_children static, as well as the CanCreate() method